# TSQL update with select join issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I took some code which supposed to work and see it doesn't work as desinged,
I frankly struggling to get what is wrong, I need to fill all basket, but now only first got filled, Do I need to do any pivot ?? or get rid of update with select? Id'like to have same 5 Tx rows, and fill all basket for ALL TxID, this self inclusive example below will illustrate this:

```
 SELECT * INTO #lkup FROM (      -- drop table #lkup       -- select * from #lkup
 SELECT   201  Cust_ID, 1    Line,  'Pr1' ProductID    UNION
 SELECT   201  Cust_ID, 2    Line,  'Pr20' ProductID    UNION
 SELECT   201  Cust_ID, 3    Line,  'Pr333' ProductID      ) g

 SELECT * INTO #tx FROM (  -- drop table #tx       -- select * from #tx
 SELECT 201  Cust_ID, cast (NULL AS varchar(7)) Prod1,  cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod2, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod3 , 12001 TxID  UNION 
 SELECT 201  Cust_ID, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod1,  cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod2, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod3 , 12002 TxID  UNION
 SELECT 201  Cust_ID, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod1,  cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod2, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod3 , 12003 TxID  UNION
 SELECT 201  Cust_ID, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod1,  cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod2, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod3 , 12004 TxID  UNION
 SELECT 201  Cust_ID, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod1,  cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod2, cast (NULL AS varchar(7))  Prod3 , 12005 TxID   ) g


 UPDATE tx
 SET Prod1 = CASE WHEN LINE =1 THEN ProductID END,
      Prod2 = CASE WHEN LINE =2 THEN ProductID END,
       Prod3 = CASE WHEN LINE =3 THEN ProductID END
--- SELECT l.Line, l.ProductID, tx.*
 FROM #tx tx
 JOIN #lkup l ON l.Cust_ID = tx.Cust_ID

 SELECT * FROM #tx         -- update #tx  set Prod1 = '    ', Prod2 = '    ', Prod3 = '    '
 SELECT 'Shouldbe' , '201' CustID, 'Pr1' Prod1, 'Pr20' Prod1, 'Pr333' Prod1, 12001 TxID     -- for each Tx 5 rows Total
```

Comment: fascinating. it is probably undefined (or indeterminate) behavior. try replacing the update statement's `JOIN` by `RIGHT JOIN` and see what happens. could you just rewrite the `CASE` stuff with subqueries to `#lkup`?

Comment: Tx I tried use (Select ) in parenthesis instead of Case and it doesn't take it, probably b'z of UPDATE syntax.  with RIGHT JOIN it captures now Prod1 AND Prod3, but still not Prod2 (?).

Comment: Correction: this actually works, but would be my last resort, I have too man y baskets and in real setup I have nested select in JOIN. UPDATE #tx  
 SET #tx.Prod1 =    (SELECT l.ProductID FROM #lkup l WHERE l.Cust_ID = #tx.Cust_ID AND  LINE =1)

Comment: Well how would you expect this work? Which row from tx should it use as the value? Your join condition is essentially a cross join with your sample data.

Comment: Tx, Yes it's cross join, I see 15 rows, but still there rows for each LINE, I actually suprised that it works as its kind update to multiple values., I assume it brows thru all of them and it should catch correct LINE#...

Comment: UPDATE tx
 SET Prod1 = l1.ProductID ,
      Prod2 = l2.ProductID ,
       Prod3 = l3.ProductID 
--- SELECT  tx.*                          --l.%%physloc%%,
 FROM #tx tx
  JOIN #lkup l1   ON l1.Cust_ID = tx.Cust_ID   AND l1.LINE = 1
  JOIN #lkup l2   ON l2.Cust_ID = tx.Cust_ID   AND l2.LINE = 2
  JOIN #lkup l3   ON l3.Cust_ID = tx.Cust_ID   AND l3.LINE = 3

Comment: Above code works OK. I whish I could do it with single join

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block.

```
 UPDATE tx
 SET Prod1 = l.ProductID,
      Prod2 = l2.ProductID,
       Prod3 = l3.ProductID
--- SELECT l.Line, l.ProductID, tx.*
 FROM #tx tx
 LEFT JOIN #lkup l ON l.Cust_ID = tx.Cust_ID AND l.Line=1
 LEFT JOIN #lkup l2 ON l2.Cust_ID = tx.Cust_ID AND l2.Line=2
 LEFT JOIN #lkup l3 ON l3.Cust_ID = tx.Cust_ID AND l3.Line=3
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of course is that you're updating same rows more than once. It's strange that it's not an error, but if I understood your code correctly, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE tx
SET tx.Prod1 = L.Prod1,
    tx.Prod2 = L.Prod2,
    tx.Prod3 = L.Prod3
FROM #tx tx
cross apply (
    SELECT 
         Cust_ID,
         Prod1 = max(CASE WHEN LINE =1 THEN ProductID END),
         Prod2 = max(CASE WHEN LINE =2 THEN ProductID END),
         Prod3 = max(CASE WHEN LINE =3 THEN ProductID END)
    FROM #lkup
    group by Cust_ID
) L where L.Cust_ID = tx.Cust_ID
```

Result:

```
    Cust_ID Prod1   Prod2   Prod3   TxID
1   201     Pr1     Pr20    Pr333   12001
2   201     Pr1     Pr20    Pr333   12002
3   201     Pr1     Pr20    Pr333   12003
4   201     Pr1     Pr20    Pr333   12004
5   201     Pr1     Pr20    Pr333   12005
```